# How to stop this script from loading up on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have been trying to stop this below mentioned script from getting loaded on mobile devices but can't.
Can anyone please edit the script or code and make it non-loadable on mobile devices?

Blog Address - [answer key](http://answerkeydownload.net/).

Thanks in advance!

```js
<style type="text/css">
#topbar{
position: absolute;
border: 0px solid black;
padding: 1px;
width: 120px;
height: 600px;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 1;
}
</style>



<script type="text/javascript">

var persistclose=0 //set to 0 or 1. 1 means once the bar is manually closed, it will remain closed for browser session
var startX = 1 //set x offset of bar in pixels
var startY = 1 //set y offset of bar in pixels
var verticalpos="fromtop" //enter "fromtop" or "frombottom"

function iecompattest(){
return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
}

function get_cookie(Name) {
var search = Name + "="
var returnvalue = "";
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
if (offset != -1) {
offset += search.length
end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
}
}
return returnvalue;
}

function closebar(){
if (persistclose)
document.cookie="remainclosed=1"
document.getElementById("topbar").remove()
}

function staticbar(){
 barheight=document.getElementById("topbar").offsetHeight
 var ns = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") != -1) || window.opera;
 var d = document;
 function ml(id){
  var el=d.getElementById(id);
  if (!persistclose || persistclose && get_cookie("remainclosed")=="")
  el.style.visibility="visible"
  if(d.layers)el.style=el;
  el.sP=function(x,y){this.style.left=x+"px";this.style.top=y+"px";};
  el.x = startX;
  if (verticalpos=="fromtop")
  el.y = startY;
  else{
  el.y = ns ? pageYOffset + innerHeight : iecompattest().scrollTop + iecompattest().clientHeight;
  el.y -= startY;
  }
  return el;
 }
 window.stayTopLeft=function(){
  if (verticalpos=="fromtop"){
  var pY = ns ? pageYOffset : iecompattest().scrollTop;
  ftlObj.y += (pY + startY - ftlObj.y)/8;
  }
  else{
  var pY = ns ? pageYOffset + innerHeight - barheight: iecompattest().scrollTop + iecompattest().clientHeight - barheight;
  ftlObj.y += (pY - startY - ftlObj.y)/8;
  }
  ftlObj.sP(ftlObj.x, ftlObj.y);
  setTimeout("stayTopLeft()", 10);
 }
 ftlObj = ml("topbar");
 stayTopLeft();
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", staticbar, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", staticbar)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=staticbar
</script>

<div id="topbar">
<a href="" onClick="closebar(); return false"><img src="http://answerkeydownload.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/close.gif" border="0" /></a>
Advertisement< here goes my ad code>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: I think this is what you need: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};


var persistclose=0 //set to 0 or 1. 1 means once the bar is manually closed, it will remain closed for browser session
var startX = 1 //set x offset of bar in pixels
var startY = 1 //set y offset of bar in pixels
var verticalpos="fromtop" //enter "fromtop" or "frombottom"

function iecompattest(){
return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
}

function get_cookie(Name) {
var search = Name + "="
var returnvalue = "";
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
if (offset != -1) {
offset += search.length
end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
}
}
return returnvalue;
}

function closebar(){
if (persistclose)
document.cookie="remainclosed=1"
document.getElementById("topbar").remove()
}

function staticbar(){
  if (window.mobilecheck)
    return false;

 barheight=document.getElementById("topbar").offsetHeight
 var ns = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") != -1) || window.opera;
 var d = document;
 function ml(id){
  var el=d.getElementById(id);
  if (!persistclose || persistclose && get_cookie("remainclosed")=="")
  el.style.visibility="visible"
  if(d.layers)el.style=el;
  el.sP=function(x,y){this.style.left=x+"px";this.style.top=y+"px";};
  el.x = startX;
  if (verticalpos=="fromtop")
  el.y = startY;
  else{
  el.y = ns ? pageYOffset + innerHeight : iecompattest().scrollTop + iecompattest().clientHeight;
  el.y -= startY;
  }
  return el;
 }
 window.stayTopLeft=function(){
  if (verticalpos=="fromtop"){
  var pY = ns ? pageYOffset : iecompattest().scrollTop;
  ftlObj.y += (pY + startY - ftlObj.y)/8;
  }
  else{
  var pY = ns ? pageYOffset + innerHeight - barheight: iecompattest().scrollTop + iecompattest().clientHeight - barheight;
  ftlObj.y += (pY - startY - ftlObj.y)/8;
  }
  ftlObj.sP(ftlObj.x, ftlObj.y);
  setTimeout("stayTopLeft()", 10);
 }
 ftlObj = ml("topbar");
 stayTopLeft();
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", staticbar, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", staticbar)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=staticbar
```

```css
#topbar{
position: absolute;
border: 0px solid black;
padding: 1px;
width: 120px;
height: 600px;
visibility: hidden;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
<a href="" onClick="closebar(); return false"><img src="http://answerkeydownload.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/close.gif" border="0" /></a>
Advertisement< here goes my ad code>
</div>
```

you can use this Regexp to check if it's on a mobile browser:

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually I don't have much knowledge of coding or scripting and to be really honest I don't know where to put your code in my code. Also, I want to completely block this script on mobile devices, so if you can help me out it that, then it would be really great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Daniel here it goes the complete example. Just put each part (css, js and html) where it should be. I've just adde the check condition inside your function staticbar-

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it didn't work, it actually made the close button disappear and also it restricted the sliding feature of the script. Don't know how this happened but it didn't work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the preferred way or not. But this is what I've used:

```
if (window.innerWidth >= 800 && window.innerHeight >= 600) {
       //your function call
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 media query API, called the `window.matchMedia`.

For example:

```
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 768px)" );
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  // your code on mobile or small screen devices
} else {
  // your code on everything else
}
```

Working Snippet (*check inline and also expand snippet*):

```js
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 768px)" );
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  console.log('small screen code runs here');
} else {
  console.log('big screen code runs here');
}
```